# What is this distributed communication model called (client-server-engine)?

Tags: c++, networking, communication, boost-beast

I'm looking for a communication model that is constructed the following way:

- One or more clients can connect to a server
- One (chess-)engine connects to the server

The information flow is only one way, e.g if any client sends a message to the server, the server will forward the message to the engine. But if the engine responds, it should first send the respond to the server which forwards the response to the specific client. 
Additionally, do you have any ideas or code examples on how to program that using c++ with boost/beast?